# Generate ed25519 key-pair compatible with openssh

Tags: go, openssh

I want to generate an ssh key compatible with openssh using ed25519 in go to replace
**rsa.GenerateKey** since github does not support it anymore.

It should be the equivalent of:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

But I can't find a way to do it.

For now, I have this code:

```
func GenerateSSHKeys() (*ED25519Keys, error) {
    publicKey, privateKey, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    publicED25519Key, err := ssh.NewPublicKey(publicKey)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pubKeyBytes := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(publicED25519Key)

    bytes, err := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(privateKey) 
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    privBlock := pem.Block{
        Type:    "PRIVATE KEY",
        Headers: nil,
        Bytes:   bytes,
    }

    privatePEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(&privBlock)

    return &ED25519Keys{
        Public:  pubKeyBytes,
        Private: privatePEM,
    }, nil

}
```

But it seems that the private key is shorter, and I can't explain some weird behavior that I have using it with git or argocd (sometimes it works, but most of the time no).

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEINV+5Hyey1xTblwsVGfGmDCMdZgKQdhf1ublkGO2Qaf+
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I end up with something like that :

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACAxIu+ndqJXpEJLk5c2qsjPvUybP8OANZlSqLaOau9ZCQAAAKCocC5dqHAu
[...]
AAAEChVq8FJPCYbKnNFFuISac83mzF+DDFCDrLd9Xva9fQ2zEi76d2olekQkuTlzaqyM+9
TJs/w4A1mVKoto5q71kJAAAAFnlvdXJfZW1haWxAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20BAgMEBQYH
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I've run into this as well.

The `x509` package does not support marshaling `ed25519` key types in the format used by `openssh`, so as you've discovered, this code - which works with other key types - fails for `ed25519` keys:

```
bytes, err := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(privateKey)  // produces invalid output for ed25519 keys
```

There is a repo ([github.com/mikesmitty/edkey](https://github.com/mikesmitty/edkey/)) with a helper function [edkey.MarshalED25519PrivateKey](https://github.com/mikesmitty/edkey/blob/master/edkey.go#L10) to address this:

> /* Writes ed25519 private keys into the new OpenSSH private key
> format. I have no idea why this isn't implemented anywhere yet, you
> can do seemingly everything except write it to disk in the OpenSSH
> private key format. */

it seems to be modeled on the openssh source: `sshkey.c` [sshkey_private_to_blob2](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_9_0_P1/sshkey.c#L3910)

So either copy that helper function into your code (recommended as repo from `2017` is several years old) or reference it as an import:

```
import "github.com/mikesmitty/edkey"

pubKey, privKey, _ := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
publicKey, _ := ssh.NewPublicKey(pubKey)

pemKey := &pem.Block{
    Type:  "OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY",
    Bytes: edkey.MarshalED25519PrivateKey(privKey),  // <- marshals ed25519 correctly
}
privateKey := pem.EncodeToMemory(pemKey)
authorizedKey := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(publicKey)

_ = ioutil.WriteFile("id_ed25519", privateKey, 0600)
_ = ioutil.WriteFile("id_ed25519.pub", authorizedKey, 0644)
```

Comment: Is this still relevant? The docs state, that the function supports ed25519: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and finally solved it. Here's how to do this now using only the stdlibs:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/ed25519"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    // If rand is nil, crypto/rand.Reader will be used
    pub, priv, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    p, err := ssh.MarshalPrivateKey(crypto.PrivateKey(priv), "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    privateKeyPem := pem.EncodeToMemory(p)
    privateKeyString := string(privateKeyPem)
    publicKey, err := ssh.NewPublicKey(pub)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    publicKeyString := "ssh-ed25519" + " " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(publicKey.Marshal())
    fmt.Printf("Private Key:\n%s\n", privateKeyString)
    fmt.Printf("Public Key:\n%s\n", publicKeyString)
}
```